# How do I control how much a browser auto scrolls when focus shifts to off-screen element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, focus

After 6 hours of beating my head against a wall...

I have an html form with a series of inputs, arranged in a grid, with enough in each column so that there is overflow on the page and thus a scrollbar. The inputs have tab indexes, so it's like a data entry form. You can enter information into the text inputs and tab. The tab indexes are such that as you tab you go all the way down the first column and then goes to the top of the next column, etc.  When you get to the bottom and you tab into an element that is off-screen, the browser repositions so that the element is now in the viewable space.

Here's the problem. Chrome and Edge automatically scroll down a sizable amount when this happens, but FF and IE only scroll a little bit. I want FF and IE to scroll by a larger amount, but I don't know how to control it. Also, when you tab from the last input in a column, which puts you into the top input of the next column, Chrome and Edge scroll all the way up to the top so that the element you just tabbed into is well within the viewable area. FF and IE, though... they don't even manage to scroll all the way up, so the element is either barely in the viewable area or not in the viewable area forcing you to use the scroll bar to finish the job.

It seems like there should be some setting for how much the browser should scroll when it finds itself forced to scroll because you changed focus to an element that is off the screen. I've thought about putting a focus event listener in so that if you begin approaching the edges of visible space as you tab through the inputs, I go ahead and force my own scroll (window.scrollBy(0,50)), but it's just frustrating to think there must be some global scroll amount, or scroll margin, or what have you, that could be set so that all the browsers scroll by the same amount when you tab into (focusin) an element that happens to be outside of the viewable area.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions. I guess if there isn't some kind of css property that handles this on the window or document, then it's a matter of taking over the job of scrolling from the browser and implement it myself in the focus method.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am having the same problems.